# Inserting Modified field into Word documents

Tags: content-type, word, quick-parts

I am trying to insert the Modified metadata field into the Word documents using Quick parts but I can't see the field in field lists.

How can I add this field to any Word document by using content types?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't tried this, but you could create a new date column and on item edit, copy the modified date into that column via workflow or event receiver and use that in the quick part.

Comment: That is exactly what I am doing right now, it works but I thought there should be a better way.